# Celery + Redis Issue

Tags: python, redis, celery

I've got an app that works as expected in celery until I set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False.

```
# main file
jobs = get_report_jobs_from_db()

for job in jobs:
    out = run_job.delay(job)

status, id = out.state, out.task_id
# Should be status string and UUID.
save_job(job, status, id) # record to db
# On bad calls status == id and is a UUID.



# celery file
from foo import do_something, write_id_back

@celery.task
def run_job(job):
  id = do_something(job)  # do_something returns a report_id
  write_id_back(job, id) # write that id back to the originating job record

#foo file 

def do_something(job):
    prep_data = prep_job(job)
    report_id = mysql_insert(job, prep_data)
    # A report_id is returned if the insert suceeds otherwise it is
    # null. The INSERT always works if I run 
    # CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True, but if redis is involved it fails
    # routinely
    return report_id
```

---

If I run my code under CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True, bypassing redis, I get all my report_ids back attached to my originating jobs. This is what I want.

However, once I set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False, I get all of my report_ids written back except for 3, and they are always the same ones. These three jobs are similar in important ways that differentiate them from the other jobs.

Now, here's what I don't get. If I shuffle the jobs list (i.e. random.shuffle(jobs), I get 6-8 failed id writes. It varies.

Can anyone give me an idea of what might be happening here?

Also, when I try to check the state of the task_id for the jobs that are failing instead of getting a state string (e.g. 'PENDING','SUCCESS'), I get the task_id hash back.

Any idea how to debug this issue, or what it might be?

Comment: can you show more code and output that illustrates what is going on?

Comment: My big concern at the moment is why is celery returning a UUID instead of a state description string for state for the failing jobs?

Comment: well you haven't really shown the output - you just put some comments in your code. update with the actual output, from, say ipython, that illustrates exactly what is going on

Comment: I'm having a difficult time getting useful feedback. That's part of the problem. The big question I have now is why would celery return a task_id instead of a state in the AsyncResult for the bad entries?

Comment: you're not getting useful feedback because you haven't provided useful information, and you ignore requests to give that information.

Comment: By feedback, I meant system feedback from the logs. The critical messages aren't there. Why does that MySQL insert only fail when it's run with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True, for example? I'm trying to figure out how to figure out how to get access to the logging messages I need to see to work this out. I'm asking general questions to see if I can get any clues as to how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were multiple celery instances running.

If you are running into weird celery issues that defy conventional investigation make sure to check you celery processes:

```
ps -ef | grep celery
```

Make sure you recognize all of them. In my case there was an old celery process running out of supervisor that I had forgotten about. It only interfered in certain situations, and would swallow my logging attempts when it did to some mystery location.